# Snabbdom - Not able to load javascript file into snabbdom project

Tags: javascript, embed, web-component

I want to embed a web-component based javascript file into the snabbdom based project but not able to load it into the project.

Also not able to find that particular javascript file in the dist folder after building the project.

const view = (state, {updateState}) => {

```
function AddLibrary(urlOfTheLibrary) {
    console.log("add librar",urlOfTheLibrary);
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = urlOfTheLibrary;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

return (
    <div>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <sg-bar hook-init={AddLibrary("/sg-bar.js")}></sg-bar>
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)